# Setting managedObjectContext in AppDelegate

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to learn the basics of core data and have started a single view application whilst having a basic template of the master-detail application with core data open for reference.

I'm stuck trying to set my managedObjectContext within my MasterViewController via AppDelegate.swift.

I have this so far, the master-detail template uses a split view which I'm not using, so how can I do a similar thing with only a single-view application?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // How to reference MasterViewController???

    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the managed object context all over the app using the following line of code.

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

So you can remove the following line.

```
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
```

Comment: Okay, cool so I've got just that line in my application() function in AppDelegate.swift

So how do I access that in, say my MasterViewController?

Comment: For convenience, you can add a static property into AppDelegate 
    static var mObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {return (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext}

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend **passing** the `NSManagedObjectContext` to the appropriate view controller/s as recommended in the Apple documents.
This involves the following steps:

- prepare your Core Data stack;
- retain a strong reference to the `NSManagedObjectContext` prepared in the Core Data stack;
- include an `NSManagedObjectContext` public property in your (swift) view controller file;
- **set** that public property in the view controller from the reference held in the stack.

From the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html)...

> **Getting a Managed Object Context**
>
> **In iOS:**
>
> By convention, you get a context from a view controller. You must
>   implement your application appropriately, though, to follow this
>   pattern.
>
> When you implement a view controller that integrates with Core Data,
>   you can add an NSManagedObjectContext property.
>
> When you create a view controller, you pass it the context it should
>   use. You pass an existing context, or (in a situation where you want
>   the new controller to manage a discrete set of edits) a new context
>   that you create for it. It’s typically the responsibility of the
>   application delegate to create a context to pass to the first view
>   controller that’s displayed.
>
> A view controller typically shouldn’t retrieve the context from a
>   global object such as the application delegate—this makes the
>   application architecture rigid. Neither should a view controller
>   create a context for its own use (unless it’s a nested context). This
>   may mean that operations performed using the controller’s context
>   aren’t registered with other contexts, so different view controllers
>   will have different perspectives on the data.
>
> Sometimes, though, it’s easier or more appropriate to retrieve the
>   context from somewhere other than application or the document, or the
>   view controller. Several objects you might use in a Core Data-based
>   application keep a reference to a managed object context. A managed
>   object itself has a reference to its own context, as do the various
>   controller objects that support Core Data such as array and object
>   controllers (NSArrayController and NSObjectController in OS X, and
>   NSFetchedResultsController in iOS).
>
> Retrieving the context from one of these objects has the advantage
>   that if you re-architect your application, for example to make use of
>   multiple contexts, your code is likely to remain valid. For example,
>   if you have a managed object, and you want to create a new managed
>   object that will be related to it, you can ask original object for its
>   managed object context and create the new object using that. This will
>   ensure that the new object you create is in the same context as the
>   original.